# R make tile plot on a make based on netcdf files

Tags: r

I have two netcdf files:
-air quality values (which is the z value or filled value) record for each grid (COL, ROW, LAY, TSTEP)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SHnmzV4L1Lqjj9XMdIFQ-nQHOGRpnPhB
-longitude and latitude for each grid
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dvsh2Ct2--3Bvcux4EXoRm0ntzAVx9OW

I want to make tile plot on a map based on those information.

longitudes and latitudes are not in consist interval.

I have tried extracting part of the data and using ggplot + geom_raster
but the result is not what I expect to have

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewug2.jpg

I also tried used the whole data with geom_tile and geom_polygon, but no tile was ploted

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb0ZP.jpg

```
library(ncdf4)

#path and file
path <- "C:/Users/jhuang/Documents"
file <- "emis_mole_all_20060801_12US1_cmaq_cb05_tx_C25_2006am.ncf"
GRID <- "GRIDCRO2D_Benchmark"
#pollutant interested
poll <- "SO2"
file1 <- sprintf("%s/%s",path, file)
file2 <- sprintf("%s/%s",path, GRID)
ncin <- nc_open(file1)
gridin <- nc_open(file2)
#extract LAT and LON and also SO2 concentrations for each grid
LAT <- ncvar_get(gridin,"LAT")
LON <- ncvar_get(gridin,"LON")
data <- ncvar_get(ncin,poll)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
#extract first time step
data_1 <- data[,,1]
#organize all data into one data frame
data_2 <- data.frame(cbind(as.vector(LON),as.vector(LAT),as.vector(data_1)))
colnames(data_2) <- c("LON","LAT","POLL")

us_states <- map_data("state")
ggplot(data = data_2, aes(x=LON,y=LAT,fill=POLL)) +
  geom_tile()+
  geom_polygon(data=us_states,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="black", fill="red", alpha=0)
```

I expect to see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhfxp.jpg. I can use NCL to make this plot, just wonder is that possible to make similar plot in R.

Comment: I downloaded the data and inspecting your code. I am afraid your data is too large. When I tried to draw a graphic, vector size was extremely large. So I just used the first 100 rows of `data_2`. Can you try the following code? `ggplot() + geom_map(data = us_states, map = us_states, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region), fill = "white") + geom_raster(data = data_2[1:100, ], aes(x = LON, y = LAT, fill = POLL))`? On my side, I see tiny dots in Gulf of Mexico They seem to represent a line or something.

Comment: I figured out this is a irregular tile plot, therefore, I interp the data and reorganized grid data. If you are interested please see here for detail.
https://github.com/JiaoyanHuang/CMAQ-input/blob/master/R/CMAQmap.R

Raster did help but cannot process the entire data set, so used geom_tile instead.

thank you

Comment: I am glad that you found your way.